# Returning Multiple Records in One Column

Tags: sql

Is there a method to return multiple records of email for example in one column?  So I would not have multiple rows returned for each different email that a person has on file.
So the output for example would be for just one row with FNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL (all emails, comma separated).

ORACLE SQL
Thanks
Rich

Update:  Gordon's response was great but...
I do now have (with listagg) all the emails for each record returning in one column separated by comma as I wanted.  But there are emails listed that are repeated. Meaning johndoe@gmail.com could be listed 5 times. And, this number seems to be tied to the number of financial entries that I am summing and grouping. See my code:

```
   select
  SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID,
  SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME,
  SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME,
  SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_COLL_CODE_1,
  --tbraccd.tbraccd_amount,
  --tbraccd.tbraccd_balance,
  sum(tbraccd.tbraccd_balance) Balance,
  --tbraccd.tbraccd_detail_code,
  --tbraccd.tbraccd_desc,
  --tbraccd.tbraccd_entry_date
  listagg(goremal.goremal_email_address, ',') within group (order by goremal.goremal_email_address) as Emails

from SATURN.SPRIDEN
  inner join SATURN.SGBSTDN
    on SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM = SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM
  inner join TAISMGR.TBRACCD
    on SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM = TAISMGR.TBRACCD.TBRACCD_PIDM
   inner join general.goremal
    on SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM = GOREMAL.GOREMAL_PIDM
where SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF = '202002' 
  -- and SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID = '917181696'
  and TAISMGR.TBRACCD.TBRACCD_TERM_CODE = '202002'
  and SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND is null 
  and GOREMAL.GOREMAL_Emal_Code = 'HAPP'
group by SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID, SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME, SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME, SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_COLL_CODE_1, goremal.goremal_email_address
order by SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME
```

Thoughts?
Thank you

Update:
All fixed added DISTINCT...

```
listagg(DISTINCT goremal.goremal_email_address, ',') within group (order by goremal.goremal_email_address) as Emails
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL: How return several distinct columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56009847/oracle-sql-how-return-several-distinct-columns)

Answer (score 2):

This answers the original version of the question.

I think you want `listagg()`:

```
select fname, lastname,
       listagg(email, ',') within group (order by email) as emails
from t
group by fname, lastname;
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you!

Comment: Just one more question.  My qry is summing and grouping various costs and adding the listagg to the qry is now causing the amount of aggregated emails in that column to reflect how many transactions are being summed in the group by.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @RichC . . . A new question should be asked as a *new* question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.